# Most efficient way to retrieve a KeyValuePair from Dictionary

Tags: c#

In my app I have a `Dictionary<ContainerControl, int>`.
I need to check if a key is present in the dictionary and alter its corresponding value if  key is found or add the key if not already present.
The key for my dictionary is a ControlContainer object.
I could use this method:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<ContainerControl, int>();

/*...*/

var c = GetControl();

if (dict.ContainsKey(c))
{
    dict[c] = dict[c] + 1;
}
else
{
    dict.Add(c, 0);
}
```

but I think that this way if the key is already present, my dictionary is iterated three times: once in ContainsKey and twice in the if branch.

I wander if there is a more efficient way to do this, something like

```
var dict = new Dictionary<ContainerControl, int>();

/*...*/

var c = GetControl();

var kvp = dict.GetKeyValuePair(c); /* there is no such function in Dictionary */

if (kvp != null)
{
    kvp.Value++;
}
else
{
    dict.Add(c, 0);
}
```

This is possible using linq:

```
var kvp = dict.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Key == c);
```

but what about performance?

Comment: FYI dictionaries average O(1) lookup, so _"but I think that this way if the key is already present, my dictionary is iterated three times"_ is based on a false assumption of how dictionaries work. O(n) is the worst case lookup time.

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama `O(1)` operations sometimes have large values for `1`.

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama I'm curious to read more about how does lookup work and why it's O(1) in the average case. Could you provide a link? Thanks

Comment: It's because the dictionary is implemented as a hash table. Basically a hash of the key (see `GetHashCode`) is taken, and then keys are divided into buckets. When you try to access an item, the hash is used to locate the correct bucket, and specificalllllyitems with matching hashes, and then the `Equals` method is called to confirm that not only are the hashes the same, but the keys are also the same. This essentially leads to far fewer comparisons than a simple `.Where` would.

Comment: Microsoft provides some info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=net-7.0#remarks), but if you want to do a deeper dive, the .NET Framework source code is located [here](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/collections/generic/dictionary.cs).

Comment: Thank you! I found a very interesting article [here](https://blog.markvincze.com/back-to-basics-dictionary-part-1/).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As noted in comments, finding a key in a dictionary doesn't mean iterating over the whole dictionary. But in some cases it's still worth *trying* to reduce the lookups.

`KeyValuePair<,>` is a struct anyway, so if `GetKeyValuePair` *did* exist, your `kvp.Value++` wouldn't compile (as `Value` is read-only) and wouldn't work even if it did (as the pair wouldn't be the "original" in the dictionary).

You can use `TryGetValue` to reduce this to a single "read" operation and a single "write" operation:

```cs
// value will be 0 if TryGetValue returns false
if (dict.TryGetValue(c, out var value))
{
    value++;
}
dict[c] = value;
```

Or change to `ConcurrentDictionary` and use [`AddOrUpdate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentdictionary-2.addorupdate?view=net-6.0) to perform the change in a single call.

Comment: The other options is pre-seeding the dictionary at load plus control-creation-time, so at this point in the code you can logically show the entry will always already exist.

Comment: I would expect the synchronization work of ConcurrentDcitionary to significantly outweigh the time spent on a second key lookup of a Dictionary, so long as there's an even moderately sensible gethashcode implementation.

Answer (score 4):

You could also store a reference type in the dict. This means an extra allocation when you insert an item, but you can mutate items without another dictionary access. You'll need a profiler to tell you whether this is a net improvement!

```
class IntBox
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
}

if (dict.TryGetValue(c, out var box))
{
    box.Value++;
}
else
{
    dict[c] = new IntBox();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

With .NET 6 you can use [`CollectionsMarshal.GetValueRefOrAddDefault`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.collectionsmarshal.getvaluereforadddefault?view=net-6.0) for a single lookup:

```
ref int value = ref CollectionsMarshal.GetValueRefOrAddDefault(dict, c, out bool exists);
if(exists) value++; // changes the value in the dictionary even if it's a value type
```

Demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/tnW9P5

Comment: I think it's important to note that this method is dangerous. If you call it, mutate the dictionary, and then read or write to `value`, bad things can happen

Comment: @canton7: the docs state: "Items should not be added to or removed from the `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>`while the ref TValue is in use". So keep it in mind. If you need the value further you can use a different int variable.

Comment: Yep, I'm just adding the same caution here, for those who don't read the docs and will just copy/paste your answer without realising the danger